# How to get first one "id" in a JSON using sed in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

```
'''[ {
        "id": "**49b18e99-7516-4c9a-8e1a-9d28f470512**",
        "name": "Name",
        "appId": "",
        "publishTime": "2020-05-17",
        "published": true,
        "stream": {
            "id": "aaec8d41-5201-43ab809f-3063750dffff",
            "name": "name",
            "privileges": null
        },
        "savedInProductVersion": "12.0",
        "migrationHash": "qewjhjkw-djqwhndj",
        "availabilityStatus": 1,
        "privileges": null
    }, {
    "id": "**59b18e99-7516-4c9a-8e1a-9d28f4705123**",
    "name": "Name",
    "appId": "",
    "publishTime": "2020-05-17",
    "published": true,
    "stream": {
        "id": "abec8d41-5201-43ab809f-3063750deeee",
        "name": "name",
        "privileges": null
    },
    "savedInProductVersion": "12.0",
    "migrationHash": "qewjhjkw-djqwhndj",
    "availabilityStatus": 1,
    "privileges": null
}

    ]'''
```

I want this 49b18e99-7516-4c9a-8e1a-9d28f470512 and 59b18e99-7516-4c9a-8e1a-9d28f4705123 , but using "`sed -n 's|.*"id":"\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p'`"
I am getting
49b18e99-7516-4c9a-8e1a-9d28f470512,
aaec8d41-5201-43ab809f-3063750dffff,
59b18e99-7516-4c9a-8e1a-9d28f4705123,
abec8d41-5201-43ab809f-3063750deeee
if file have multiple json objects like above given.
Then please help me to find the best command for the above-using sed only.

Comment: Does it have to be with `sed`? It's simpler to use : `jq '.[].id`

Comment: But I need to use 'sed' due to some restrictions. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
awk '
    /{ *$/ { depth++ }
    /^ *}/ { depth-- }
    (depth == 1) && sub(/^[[:space:]]*"id": *"/,"") && sub(/", *$/,"")
' file
**49b18e99-7516-4c9a-8e1a-9d28f470512**
**59b18e99-7516-4c9a-8e1a-9d28f4705123**
```

Comment: @Ed Morton Thanks for your time and yes it is working as I want.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk` and with your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting RS as "id":[ till 1st occurrence of `}`. Then using `match` function to match exact value needed by OP by using regex `"id":[[:space:]]+"[^"]*` and printing the values then.

```
awk -v RS='"id":[^}]*' '
match(RT,/"id":[[:space:]]+"[^"]*/){
  val=substr(RT,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*"/,"",val)
  print val
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you for this time, your code is also working as I want.